One of my several docker containers was randomly shutdown
I have a docker container which was recently shutdown by itself:

The container status is as follows, oddly the other containers were still up.

I see that containerd was restarted recently and docker shortly afterwards:
containerd

docker

dmesg | grep oom and dmesg | grep killed show nothing, however I see a lot of activity in dmesg more generally before and after the shutdown:

At this point I am unsure how to diagnose, in order to understand more I inspect journalctl. I cannot paste the entire log file for the time window here, so I have pasted select pieces which could be relevant.
Apologies if my question seems obvious, any advice on how I can understand a bit more about what is happening would be appreciated
Jun 26 02:59:56 onboardingproduction systemd[1]: Starting PackageKit Daemon..

 ----

Jun 26 03:00:59 onboardingproduction sudo[247264]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root

Jun 26 03:00:59 onboardingproduction sudo[247664]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.CPlat.Core.LinuxPatchExtension-1.6.54 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get -s dist-upgrade -oDir::Etc::Sourcelist=/var/lib/waage>

Jun 26 03:00:59 onboardingproduction sudo[247664]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)

----

Jun 26 03:01:56 onboardingproduction sudo[248190]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)

Jun 26 03:02:03 onboardingproduction systemd[1]: Reloading.

Jun 26 03:02:03 onboardingproduction systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/cloud-init.service:19: Unknown key name 'ConditionEnvironment' in section 'Unit', ignoring.
Jun 26 03:02:13 onboardingproduction dockerd[980]: time="2024-06-26T03:02:13.357166778Z" level=error msg="Failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: EOF" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby

Jun 26 03:02:13 onboardingproduction systemd[1]: containerd.service: Succeeded.

Jun 26 03:02:13 onboardingproduction systemd[1]: Stopped containerd container runtime.

Jun 26 03:02:13 onboardingproduction systemd[1]: containerd.service: Found left-over process 1808 (containerd-shim) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.

Jun 26 03:02:13 onboardingproduction systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.

Jun 26 03:02:14 onboardingproduction systemd[1]: dev-disk-cloud-azure_resource\x2dpart1.device: Requested dependency After=network-online.target ignored (device units cannot be delayed).

Jun 26 03:02:14 onboardingproduction systemd[1]: dev-disk-cloud-azure_resource\x2dpart1.device: Requested dependency After=network.target ignored (device units cannot be delayed).

Jun 26 03:02:14 onboardingproduction systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...

